# Is it safe to change order status before save?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipping-methods, sales-order, order-status

I have [Collect In Store](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/collect-in-store-checkout-shipping-option.html) extension installed on Magento 1.9.0.1. The client wants a different default order status when this shipping method is chosen - it should be `Processed` instead of `Pending`. I could change the status on `sales_order_place_after` event like:

```
public function changeOrderStatus($event)
{
    $order = $event->getOrder();

    if ($order->getData('shipping_method') == 'collectinstore_collectinstore') {
        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
        $order->save();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But in this case the order's default status still will be  `Pending` and later changed to `Procssed`. Also the customer will receive an email for status `Pending` but not for status `Processed`. So is it safe enough to change the order status before saving the order (`sales_order_save_before` event)? And if so, how I can stop the email notification on status `Pending` and send it when changing the status to `Processed`? On the other side it is not mentioned anywhere on the email (New order email) that the status is `Pending` or something else. So it seems okay to send it the first time and then just change the status to `Processing` but I'm still not sure if it's good enough.

**Edit:** What I was trying to achieve has nothing to do with changing the status of the order. My question is somehow wrong. Accepted **R.S**'s answer below because he helped me to understand that I don't have to change the status with observer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A order should not be set to 'Processing' until the payment is received because until payment is received the 'state' is 'new' and to set it to 'processing' the 'state' need to be 'processing'.

In your system config 
Admin -> system -> config -> Payment Methods -> {Payment Name} -> New Order Status

Order Process Mode = "Authorize Only" then  New order Status = "pending"
Order Process Mode = "Authorize & Capture" then  New order Status = "processing"

Take a look at http://www.mexbs.com/magento-order-statestatus-flow/

[image]

**Order "Pending"**
From the Admin panel, the sales order appears in the Order list as "Pending". At this point, payment has not been processed, and the order can still be canceled.

**Payment Received**
The status of the order remains "Pending" until payment is received. Depending on the payment method, you, may be notified when the transaction is authorized and in some cases, processed. The status of the order is now "Processing" and order can not be cancel and you will need to issue a credit using Credit Memos see http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/order-process-overview

Comment: We will use SagePay for the payments (credit/debit cards + PayPal). The money will be captured instantly. But the module it's not installed yet.

Comment: When changing 'status' you need to also update to the appropriate 'state', otherwise you will have issues when adding comment to order (it will change back to the default 'status' for that 'state')

Comment: As I understand I have to change the state and then the status will be changed, too? Ok, but how can I do that?

Comment: What issue are you having? Did you installed SagePay and see it you still having this issue? The only time a order will go to 'pending' is when the pending type is 'cash' or 'check' when payment receive by credit card it should automatically go to 'processing'

Comment: No, I didn't installed SagePay as the client still didn't bought it. The site is on a test server yet. But I installed the free version of SagePay (CE) and there the status is Pending even when the Invoice is generated.

Comment: Did you check your configuration in Admin -> system -> config -> Payment Methods -> SagePay -> New Order Status

Comment: You're completely right! It's set to Pending there. But I'm not sure actually whether it should be Processed by default.

Comment: Once an invoice is generated (i.e payment received) then it should be processing

Comment: The Client said the payment action will be "Authorize and Capture", so the default status always should be "Processing"?

Comment: Yes. "Authorize and Capture" should generate an invoice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18012/discussion-between-enenen-and-r-s).