# change status order to "pending payement"

Tags: invoice, order-status

I just created a custom payment method and I would like that when the invoice is generated to change the status of the order.
What function do i rewrite.

thanks

Comment: This question is too broad. Please add some information what you have already implemented or tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create and event/observer see [Run method after capturing invoice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/run-method-after-capturing-invoice)

singleton
          [Company]_[Name]_Model_Observer
          changeOrderStatus

in observer

```
class <Company>_<Name>_Model_Observer
{

    public function changeOrderStatus($observer)
    {
         $this->_invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
         $order = $invoice->getOrder();
         $order->setStatus(  ... );
         $order->save();
```

Comment: thanks.it works.i add it: public function invoiceSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Is it safe to change order status before save?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40715/is-it-safe-to-change-order-status-before-save)

Assuming that your payment is set to authorize and capture

> Once an invoice is generated then the status
>   should be processing because you should already receive payment (take a look at cash/check payment method once you invoice balance due become zero)

But if you still want to make it “pending payement”

in system.xml you need to either create a new `source_model` or find one that has pending payment status, the set it as default in system config your payment method

```
<order_status translate="label">
  <label>New order status</label>
  <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
  <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_processing</source_model>
  <sort_order>4</sort_order>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
```

Comment: in fact when the order is placed I have the "processing" status what is fine but when the invoice is created I do not capture the payment so it would have to pass in order status "pending payment". Is it possible?

Comment: What is your payment processing type set to?

Comment: it is a payment slip